# Change Outlook's default view font setting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I hate Segoe UI, but can't config Outlook to **default** choose another font (at least Tahoma) for view in all mail folder.

[image: segoe]

---

Bibhas has misunderstood me.
I'm talking about font options for "Outlook View", which you can find at `View - View Settings - Other Setting` , not about font for email content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally find the way to fix:
After config all setting you need, use
`Ribbon - View - Change View - Apply Current View to Other Mail Folder...`
That's it! Thanks for reading my question!
[image]

Comment: if you have custom colors defined (red color from emails from boss), that you may have to change fonts in those rules

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook 2010, `File > Options > Mail > Stationary and Fonts > Personal Stationary > Make the changes`.

[Source](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/change-default-email-font-settings-theme-in-outlook-2010/).