# Outlook View for Emails and Calender Appointments and suddenly changed

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I don't know why or how, but for some reason, my Outlook suddenly changed the view for emails and calendar entries. Now there is a really bad font with unnecessary spacing within words and paragraphs. I haven't found a way to change it back yet.

I tried going through the options of the view menu for example [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/388301/change-outlooks-default-view-font-setting). Unfortunately, I had no luck so far. Whatever I do to the font for viewing emails, nothing changes.

I'm using the three-pane view with the folder pane, the list/preview pane, and the message pane. The screenshot is from the message pane for an email but if you open a calendar entry it looks pretty much the same:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is Outlook Immersive Reader. I have seen this myself.

You can turn Immersive Reader OFF.   Outlook, View Tab, Immersive Reader, (Close Immersive Reader).

.

It is for sure not a font issue (I tried that myself).

.

[image: Outlook Immersive Reader]

Comment: Good call, that was it. Seems I accidentally clicked on the button. Not sure why, I never use the "view" tab.

Comment: Thanks.   I had that issue and turning off immersive reader was the answer

Comment: Anything I can improve with the question for an upvote?

Comment: Your question is quite good and represents what I saw.    +1